# Do JS event listeners cost more than an additional HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, jquery-events

I have heard that it is best to condense all your JavaScript into one file to reduce the number of HTTP requests your application makes. However, does this hold true if you make use of event listeners that are each specific to only one page of a site?

For example, say I have 3 different pages that make AJAX requests to load a random picture from the server. The first page listens for a button click, the second page listens for a `mouseover`, and the third page listens for a change in the value of a select field. Does it make sense to have one giant JS file that contains all DOM-manipulation logic, as well as the event listeners? Or is it better to define all the necessary DOM-manipulation logic in one file and then have one small JS file for each page with the page-specific event listeners for that page.

TL;DR: Do event listeners for elements that do not exist on the page cost more in performance than HTTP requests for an additional JS file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832

Comment: There really isn't a clear cut answer for this. For example...What does `giant file` mean in real size? How many listeners? without more granular details the whole thing is open to a lot of opinions and is therefore off topic

Comment: The question at the end just adds more confusion. Anyway, 'listeners' (function objects, wiring, execution) are 'very cheap', and the 'code cost' to add a useful event listener is probably only a few dozen lines.. consider that even a normal-sized image these days is *hundreds of kilobytes of non-compressible data* (as PNG/JPG etc are already near limits), a few thousands characters of (easily http-compressible) JavaScript is insignificant in comparison.

Comment: (There are also module packagers/loaders/minifiers/etc. tooling to make JavaScript easier to write and maintain while preserving desired - and configurable - deployment strategies.)

Comment: I apologize that my question seems confusing. This was sort of a general question, and I know that the solution always depends on the scope of your project. On the other hand, I felt that asking it in a general manner was better than posting it with a heap of example code that no one would read.

Answer (score 1):

Reduction of the number of requests is one reason for consolidating JavaScript files into one.

The other reason is this: the JavaScript file can, after the browser has downloaded it just once, be retrieved from the browser cache when subsequent pages use it. Fewer files means more streamlined caching.

The cost of a little extra JavaScript is minimal. Jquery style listeners attached to no DOM elements only cost while the onload method is trying to attach them.

So do it the easy way. When you have tens of millions of page views per hour is the time to do the kind of optimizations your question mentions.

There's no harm in inlining small amounts, or even medium amounts, of JavaScript if it's easier. Do View Source on a search engine's front door page for example.